# I get a 400 error code when trying to validate a jwt token endpoint .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to validate a jwt token so I am having it sent to me within the header of my request but I get a 400 error when I pass in my token.

```
 [HttpPost("validateToken/{token}")]
        public IActionResult ValidateToken ([FromRoute] string token)
        {
            var jwthandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwttoken = jwthandler.ReadJwtToken(token);
            var expDate = jwttoken.ValidTo;
            if (expDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(3))
            {
                return Ok("invalid");

            }
            else
            {
                return Ok("valid");
            }
        }
```

I can pass in any string but when I pass in a token it fails. I may not be doing this right any help would be apperciated

Comment: Will the debugger stop if you put a breakpoint within that method?
The request may be not routed to this action method.

Comment: It's a `string`, not a `DateTime`, I think you are missing something,

Comment: @Ofiris sorry for that last comment that was meant for a different issue. So I changed this endpoint to accept the string from the body because the debugger doesn't hit. but now it is saying input was not valid so debugger is still not hitting I also changed the method from IactionResult to public string and then the return to return just a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change you code to this and pass your token as a string in the body and your logic should work

```
 [HttpPost("validateToken")]
        public string ValidateToken ([FromBody] string token)
        {
            var jwthandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwttoken = jwthandler.ReadJwtToken(token);
            var expDate = jwttoken.ValidTo;
            if (expDate < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(3))
            {
                return ("invalid");

            }
            else
            {
                return("valid");
            }
        }
```